# Powershell loop through two arrays and add content to file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have to add text from one file to the end of another file, but the contents of one file is significantly shorter than the other, so I want to keep looping through the shorter file until the longer file is complete.  I generate the intial file (scopeout.txt) with the following code

```
$a = "NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope "
$b = " set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS "
$Scopelist = Get-Content C:\ListOfScopes.txt

foreach ($i in $ListOfScopes)

{
$a + $i + $b >> C:\TestArea\scopeout.txt
}
```

I then have a file called newdns.txt that contains 4 entries (192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.11, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.13).  I want to read each line of scopeout.txt, add 1 entry from newdns.txt, then move onto the next line in each file.  I want to repeat this process until scopeout.txt is finished, so the final file will look similar to the following:

```
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.50.1 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.10
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.51.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.11
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.52.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.12
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.53.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.13
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.54.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.10
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.55.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.11
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.56.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.12
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.57.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.13
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope 192.168.58.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.10
NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 scope 192.168.59.0 set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS 192.168.0.11
```

I have experimented with using a foreach statement, but I am unsure how to combine 2 foreach statements and also how to keep looping through the newdns.txt until scopeout.txt is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$c = 0
$ip = Get-Content C:\newdns.txt

Get-Content C:\ListOfScopes.txt | Foreach-Object{
    if ($c -gt 3) {$c=0} 
    "NETSH Dhcp Server 192.168.10.1 Scope $_ set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS $($ip[$c])"
    $c++
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help